# socks5 в Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: visual-basic, vb6

можно ли написать socks5 в Visual Basic 6.0? прокси

Comment: [FreeVBCode code snippet: Sample Socks5 Proxy Server Demo](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5057) .